# Multiple TestNG Reports to one Report

Tags: testng, jenkins

Currently I have 20+ Test Suite which run as individual Job in jenkins. This will generate respective testng report on the nodes that it ran (index.html). can i consolidate all the 20+ reports into one report and show the reports for each cycle of execution.

Comment: are those test suite running in parallel of each other at the same time or not?

Comment: @YuZhang Yes all the test suites/jobs runs in parallel on available nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While generating reports I use `org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter` and 
`org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter` from reportNG framework.

I use the following Ant Task to combine reports:

```
<target name="report.nightly" description="Generates the junit test report  project."> 

        <junitreport todir="${reports.combine}/logs"> 

            <!--testNg reports --> 
                <fileset dir="${reports.testng}/logs"> 
                        <include name="*/*.xml"/> 
                </fileset> 

          <!--junit  reports --> 
                <fileset dir="${reports.junit}/logs"> 
                        <include name="TEST-*.xml" /> 
                </fileset> 

                <!--consolidated reports --> 
                <report format="frames" todir="${artifacts.tests}" /> 
        </junitreport> 

</target>
```